# Cardano-cli minting gives FeeTooSmallUTxO error when no collateral

Tags: cardano-cli, minting, collateral

For minting some tokens I use this transaction:

```
cardano-cli transaction build
  --testnet-magic 2
  --tx-in-collateral 44ed21bc50eecc24e892a5bad4a98f2187b66d1f5074db22763cbc69fb5910b6#1
  --tx-in 44ed21bc50eecc24e892a5bad4a98f2187b66d1f5074db22763cbc69fb5910b6#1
  --tx-out "addr_test1vqffq45nzrdsprua0nakp8f44xp6mzvrscmpq8alg9w888s63fusl 2000000
                + 1 59f6d5ab2a1849c6080c05aa6fee05df34c4fcb1ba0f22eb4344405b.6a6176656c696e"
  --mint "1 59f6d5ab2a1849c6080c05aa6fee05df34c4fcb1ba0f22eb4344405b.6a6176656c696e"
  --change-address addr_test1vqffq45nzrdsprua0nakp8f44xp6mzvrscmpq8alg9w888s63fusl   
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json
  --minting-script-file policy.script
  --babbage-era
  --out-file unsigned.json
```

It submits perfectly and a token gets minted:

```
Estimated transaction fee: Lovelace 179229
Transaction successfully submitted.
```

But when I remove the **--tx-in-collateral** line (thinking you don't really need it for simple tokens), and submitting this similar transaction ...

```
cardano-cli transaction build
  --testnet-magic 2
  --tx-in 53617a238110219e7d8dded048c6a497dc4ac253fa6e4bb80842bcb82b61bb93#1
  --tx-out "addr_test1vqffq45nzrdsprua0nakp8f44xp6mzvrscmpq8alg9w888s63fusl 2000000 
                + 1 59f6d5ab2a1849c6080c05aa6fee05df34c4fcb1ba0f22eb4344405b.6a6176656c696e"
  --mint "1 59f6d5ab2a1849c6080c05aa6fee05df34c4fcb1ba0f22eb4344405b.6a6176656c696e"
  --change-address addr_test1vqffq45nzrdsprua0nakp8f44xp6mzvrscmpq8alg9w888s63fusl
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json    
  --minting-script-file policy.script
  --babbage-era
  --out-file unsigned.json
```

I get this **FeeTooSmallUTxO** error (on submitting) :

```
Estimated transaction fee: Lovelace 170913
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: 
   ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError 
     [UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (FromAlonzoUtxoFail (FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 175181) (Coin 170913))))])
```

I wouldn't expect a FeeTooSmallUTxO error! Can this be a bug in cardano-cli ?
Or do I need need to add any other parameters? Or do simple tokens also need collateral?

(for ref: transactions executed on preview network with cardano-cli 1.35.5 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10, the policy.script contains { "keyHash": "6c835e5..bcf986d0c", "type": "sig" } )

Comment: You don't need collateral unless evaluating a plutus script.  I cannot reproduce this, perhaps something has changed since. Would you mind trying node and cli 1.35.6?

Comment: It just occurred to me that you might be providing more than one signing key to witnesses this transaction (e.g. when using `sign` cmd). If that's the case you must override the number of witnesses during `build` using `--witness-override`. This is because the balancing algorithm won't know how many signatures are required and assuming just one would underestimate the fee as a result. Use of the collateral input would increase the calculated fee, which would explain why this error wasn't seen previously.

Comment: Cardano Node 1.35.5 is still tagged as the latest release on https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node. Where do I get hold of 1.35.6? (without having to build it myself)

Comment: @james The `--witness-override` solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem: add `--witness-override` to the transaction build.

Here are the transaction build/sign/submit statements:

```
cardano-cli transaction build
  --testnet-magic 2    
  --tx-in 53617a238110219e7d8dded048c6a497dc4ac253fa6e4bb80842bcb82b61bb93#1
  --tx-out "addr_test1vqffq45nzrdsprua0nakp8f44xp6mzvrscmpq8alg9w888s63fusl 2000000 
        + 1 59f6d5ab2a1849c6080c05aa6fee05df34c4fcb1ba0f22eb4344405b.6a6176656c696e"
  --mint "1 59f6d5ab2a1849c6080c05aa6fee05df34c4fcb1ba0f22eb4344405b.6a6176656c696e"
  --change-address addr_test1vqffq45nzrdsprua0nakp8f44xp6mzvrscmpq8alg9w888s63fusl
  --protocol-params-file protocol-parameters.json
  --minting-script-file policy.script
  --witness-override 2    
  --babbage-era    
  --out-file unsigned.json

cardano-cli transaction sign
  --testnet-magic 2
  --tx-body-file unsigned.json    
  --signing-key-file javelin.skey
  --signing-key-file policy.skey     
  --out-file signed.json


cardano-cli transaction submit
  --testnet-magic 2
  --tx-file signed.json

Estimated transaction fee: Lovelace 175357
Transaction successfully submitted.
```

When trying the above without the `--override-witness`, I got this error:

```
Estimated transaction fee: Lovelace 170913
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage 
  (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure 
  (FromAlonzoUtxoFail (FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 175181) (Coin 170913))))])
```

(tested using 1.35.5)